# How are date features utilized in Microsoft Azure Machine Studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Microsoft Azure Machine Learning and was wondering if anyone had done some experiments on date time features. Doe sit automatically derive additional features like "day of week", "day of month", "hour of day" from them, or do I have to provide these?

I could not find any info in the official documentation (and a lack of a Microsoft support forum =)

Comment: Here is a link to the MSDN forum for Azure Machine Learning https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=MachineLearning&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc

Comment: Thanks, I'll check there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure ML supports "execute-R" module which can be easily used to accomplish this in R - few examples below

x<-as.Date("12/3/2009", "%m/%d/%Y")

> months.Date(x)

[1] "December"

> weekdays.Date(x)

[1] "Thursday"

> quarters(x)

[1] "Q4"

Comment: By the way, Microsoft forum for Azure ML is here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=MachineLearning

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the MS forum, I know with R I can explicitly do this. But I was wondering in general because it detects it as a date time feature, so when training a model with it, would be interesting to know if it considers all other derived features.